# Strech an image in css

Tags: css, html

i am new in the web development field, so i got stuck at the background itself. i tried stretch this image(img3.jpg) in the html file using  which they say isnt supported in HTML5, but i got some weird output and it was a catastrophe, so can you tell me how to get me image to stretch full 100% of the webpage ??

```
 body {
background: #08121A;    background-image: url('../img3.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #545B64;
font-weight: 300;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `background-size: cover;` like this

```
body {
    background: #08121A;
    /*-----------------------------*/
    background-image: url('../img3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;
    /*-----------------------------*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #545B64;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

> Works in:
>
> ```
> Safari 3+
> Chrome Whatever+
> IE 9+
> Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
> Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you never specified width

```
width: 100%;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `height` and `widht` properties.

```
 body {
background: #08121A;    background-image: url('../img3.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
font-size: 1.1em;
color: #545B64;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: You probably mean width, not weight, and those are not tags but properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{   
    background: #08121A url("../img3.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #545B64;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
}
```